# Definition of "as to own"?

Tags: archaicisms

Prepping for the GED RLA test, I came across this sentence (from Excerpt from A Defense of the Constitution of Government of the USA by John Adams):

> If we should extend our candor **so far as to own**

My attempts to find the meaning of *own* in this context have all failed, so I'm hereby kindly asking for your help.

Here's the full excerpt:

> *If we should extend our candor so far as to own*, that the
> majority of men are generally under the dominion of
> benevolence and good intentions, yet, it must be confessed,
> that a vast majority frequently transgress; and, what is more
> directly to the point, not only a majority, but almost all, confine
> their benevolence to their families, relations, personal friends,
> parish, village, city, county, province, and that very few,
> indeed, e?tend it impartially to the whole community.

Comment: Too brief to say much, but a guess is that own refers to admitting something, or accepting it.

Comment: Yes, own = admit in this text.

Comment: I've added the full excerpt.